# Retaining and combining rendered pixels

Tags: opengl, sdl

Note: In mine OpenGL project i have enabled `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers`, like so `SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1)`.

How do i retain the pixels after calling `SDL_GL_SwapBuffers()`, so to reuse the rendered pixels without having to render them again, and than how do i combine the retained pixels as the background layer, clear the buffer with `glClear()` and render polygons on top the background layer?

Provide commented sample code.

Comment: `Provide commented sample code.` SO does not operate this way.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you might be able to get the old contents of the backbuffer back depending on what swap method you have selected. This is a total hack, but it could work. If it is exchange, if you swap buffers again without clearing the color buffer you might have an old copy of the frontbuffer lying around in the backbuffer. If your swap method is copy, then your backbuffer should never be cleared unless you issue `glClear (...)` yourself. Be careful, because there is a third common swap option that leaves the contents of the buffers undefined if you try to read them after swapping.

The last swap behavior I mentioned is common on embedded graphics devices, like PowerVR (iOS). Not so much on desktops. And this all assumes that OpenGL's window system implementation is using 1 frontbuffer and 1 backbuffer, which brings me back to the statement that *this is a total hack*. Behind the scenes implementations can implement triple-buffering, and most of the window system APIs do not even provide a way to request the number of backbuffers let alone query it. Swap chains are nasty things in the GL world :-\

In short, ***frame amortized rendering*** (using values computed during prior frames to finish an algorithm) can be accomplished in OpenGL but you will only make life more difficult if you try to use the actual front/backbuffer(s) that the window system (e.g. WGL, glX, CGL, EGL) uses. What you need to do is quite simple, draw into an FBO and manage a swap-chain of FBOs yourself. This will unfortunately increase memory requirements, but it is how most modern graphics engines do amortization.

You will need to lookup FBOs yourself for this one, I explained the theory and that is really all you can expect (for future reference) since the question did not include any code.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I hoped there where simple solutions i was unaware to consider. I'll have to attempt your suggestions...

Comment: @8-bitButterfly: I re-read your question and I think your problem may be simpler than the title and a couple of details let on. If all you really want to do is layered rendering, you might consider clearing **ONLY** the depth buffer (**NOT** the color buffer) between layers and only swapping buffers when you finish drawing all layers.